# copy folders to user library using Terminal on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to copy a folder to the user library using the OS X Terminal. The command line I use is `cp -r`. The problem is that the command runs, but it doesn't copy the folder and it returns no error.

Exist a special command for copying folders to user library?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add the full command line you are using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are almost there. `cp` with the `-R` option and the arguments `SOURCE DESTINATION`

```
    cp -R /absolute/path/to/source/folder $HOME/Library
```

Replace `/absolute/path....../folder` with the real absolute path to the folder you wish to copy

Comment: Why can't I use a POSIX path for the library path?

Comment: `$HOME/Library` is the POSIX path to the Library folder. `$HOME` expands to `/Users/YOURNAME/`. If you want to type the absolute path to the destination directory then do so.